# org.hibernate.SessionFactory not found in Spring 3.2.3.RELEASE, but works good in 3.2.0.RELEASE

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven

I have such Maven configuration:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
...
    <dependencies>
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
...
    </dependencies>
...
</project>
```

And database-config.xml :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="***"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>database/database.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource"/>
        </property>

        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>***</value>
                <value>***</value>
            </list>
        </property>

    </bean>

</beans>
```

And also I have class:

```
@Repository
public class DataStore {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

...

```
}
```

But when I try to run the application, I get next error:

> JBWEB000071: root cause
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.SessionFactory from
>   [Module "***.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
>     org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:196)
>     org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:444)
>     org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:432)
>     org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:374)
>     org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:119)
>     java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
>     java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2308)
>     java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1760)
>     org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:324)
>     org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:840)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:910)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:853)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>     javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242)
>     org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

If I change Spring 3.2.3.RELEASE to 3.2.0.RELEASE, everything looks great. What's the difference?

Comment: Poke around what actually gets deployed to the appserver - whether the Hibernate JAR is in `WEB-INF/lib/` etc. The root cause might not be the spring version or it might in a way that causes Hibernate to not be packaged into the archive etc.

Comment: The content of target\application\WEB-INF\lib\ stays just the same, except spring-***-3.2.*.RELEASE.jar versions.

Comment: This could be a classloader issue.  If JBoss uses Spring, make sure your application is using the version you want instead of the one JBoss provides.  There is probably a way to configure the classloader.  We need to do something similar for WebLogic.